# Request Not Authorized Youtube Live streaming Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In Youtube live streaming in OAuthClient Credential. I got "Request not Authorized". I create new credentials in google api console. but i got this error Thanks Advance for Help.

```
     GoogleJsonResponseException code: 403 : Request is not authorized
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err: {
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:   "code": 403,
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:   "errors": [
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     {
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:       "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:       "message": "Request is not authorized",
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:       "reason": "insufficientLivePermissions",
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:       "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#auth_required"
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     }
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:   ],
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:   "message": "Request is not authorized"
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err: }
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.android.apps.watchme.util.YouTubeApi.createLiveEvent(YouTubeApi.java:95)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StartActivity$CreateLiveEventTask.doInBackground(StartActivity.java:326)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StartActivity$CreateLiveEventTask.doInBackground(StartActivity.java:309)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-31 19:28:48.531 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-31 19:28:48.536 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-31 19:28:48.536 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-31 19:28:48.536 19284-19810/com.ephron.mobilizerapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you enabled the YouTube Data API in your Developer Console.

The error **403 or "Request is not authorized"** is a problem regarding your authorization in the YouTube API based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/errors). So make sure that you properly follow the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication) in implementing the OAuth 2.0 Authentication. Also make sure that you use all the necessary scope.

I suggest you to try first to run your request through this [try it part](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams) to verify if the issue in in the authorization part.

Hope this information helps you.